# Bluetooth not working on HP ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

bluetooth is not working in my laptop , using hp laptop with ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

**Input : lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'**

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE  802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Ad
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
--
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:183f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b34f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 050: ID 03f0:0941 HP, Inc X500 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.117085] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.150990] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.552112] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    6.127240] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[    6.129380] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
```

**Input: systemctl | grep -i blue**

```
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1c.0-0000:01:00.0-net-wlo1.device                         loaded active     plugged   RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
  sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlo1.device                                                    loaded active     plugged   RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe (Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to ask Ubuntu,

the problem is, that you have to install the nonfree firmware. Keep sure, that your sources.list is looking into the non-free repositories and then do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install linux-firmware
sudo apt install rfkill
```

Then try `sudo rfkill list`. You should see in the output, if Bluetooth is enabled, or if its blocked by software (`soft blocked: yes`) and if it's hard blocked (`hard blocked: yes`). which is the case, when you turned off the physical switch (Disclaimer: if you deactive it in your BOIS, I don't know, if it's shown as hard blocked).

Share the output of `sudo rfkill list`.

Comment: Hey @moep thanks for your response but still not working, sudo apt install linux-firmware ---   [ linux-firmware is already the newest version (1.187.2). ]

Comment: @Ataullah khan see my edited comment.

Comment: This is all wrong. Both `linux-firmware` and `rfkill` are already installed.

Comment: @moep , here optput for sudo rfkill list --[ 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no]

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on your first output, mainly the "**01:00.0 Network controller [0280]:**" part. According this section you have the **Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless** network controller. So a simple search in GitHub of "linux driver for Ralink RT3290" it throws this result: https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms.

Downloading and installing the last version of it ([https://launchpad.net/~blaze/+archive/ubuntu/rtbth-dkms/+files/rtbth-dkms_3.9.7~git20210905-1~focal1_amd64.deb](https://launchpad.net/%7Eblaze/+archive/ubuntu/rtbth-dkms/+files/rtbth-dkms_3.9.7%7Egit20210905-1%7Efocal1_amd64.deb) published in September 2021), you can resolve your bluetooth issues. Now, according to same repository's README, you can on/off the bluetooth with few commands. What I did was define some alias in my ~/.bashrc so I can do that easly:

```
alias on='sudo modprobe rtbth ; sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth'
alias off='sudo rfkill block bluetooth && sudo pkill -2 rtbt ; sudo pkill -2 rtbt && sudo rmmod rtbth'
```

(For some reason it's not enough to apply the command pkill once, in my case.) You can also try something else that didn't work for me in order to on/off your bluetooth: that is explained in the follow blog:  https://webwiks.com/techcorner/get-ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-work-in-linux/